# Command-Tab-1, what is this?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd> and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> and tilde (<kbd>`</kbd>), we all know what this is. This is the application switcher.

But if you hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>, press <kbd>tab</kbd>, and then press <kbd>1</kbd>, and then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> other stuff happens. What is this called and how can I use it to my benefit?

*This is using a brand-new MacBook Pro with no customizations.*

Video: https://youtu.be/N8z6ozxOAag

Comment: A screenshot would help clarify your question.  There's probably hundreds of different keyboard combinations you can do when you consider the OS, apps, and 3rd-party customizations.

Comment: Question is updated to confirm no apps, customizations or other modifications are in play.

Comment: Based on what I see in the video, "with no customizations" doesn't appear to be a true statement. IMO the video does little to convey the issue because there is no visual or audio description of the events taking place. Not sure how we're supposed to know what keys are pressed other then Command-Tab as we clearly see the App Switcher, but the rest it kind of a blur!  You said. "But if you hold down Command, press tab, and then press 1, and then press tab, ~ and 1 other stuff happens.", well what do you expect when pressing a bunch of keys that are not necessarily a normal keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I will say this, if you press Command-Tab and let up Tab while still holding Command, then press 1, it's the equivalent  of a control-click on the Dock Tile of the app selected in the App Switcher and selecting Show All Windows. Not at all sure if that's what your after but that does describe what happens just with "Command-Tab and let up Tab while still holding Command, then press 1".

Answer (score 3):

It seems this invokes the 'App Exposé' feature, which shows all windows of a single application in the Mission Control display style.

[image]

It is by default available with a four-finger downward swipe on the trackpad; that will invoke this display for the currently active application, *or*, if you do it while hovering over an application icon in the Dock, for that specific application. You can change this in System Preferences → Trackpad → More Gestures:

[image]

As @user3439894 mentioned in the comments, you can also right-click an icon on the Dock and select 'Show All Windows' from the context menu:

[image]

Another option is to create a keyboard or mouse shortcut for the 'Show Application Windows' command in System Preferences → Mission Control:

[image]